# log4net not logging ThreadContext

Tags: asp.net, log4net

I have log4net running on my AsP.NET site. I'm able to log messages to my DB Table, but it isn't logging the ThreadContext properties. For example:

```
ThreadContext.Properties["Url"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
ThreadContext.Properties["HttpReferer"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

My log4net.config adds those values as parameters into my SQL DB table:

```
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@URL"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="512"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:Url}"/>
    </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@HttpReferer"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="512"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HttpReferer}"/>
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

As I debug, I see that those ThreadContext properties are being set, but they aren't getting into the DB.

How can I get that to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, it turns out the config was to blame. It was slightly wrong:

Original:

```
<conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HttpReferer}"/>
```

Changed:

```
<conversionPattern value="%property{HttpReferer}"/>
```

I had to take out the "log4net:" inside of property.

What's odd is that one property still required log4net:propertyName. I have absolutely no idea why it works this way, but that's the fix that worked!

Comment: neither one of those works for me. puzzling, because this one works %property{log4net:HostName}

Answer (score 0):

Can you turn on log4net verbose/debug/show sql to see what its doing at that level?  Is there perhaps another bit of config thats needed to tie it all together?